# What's the quickest way to get a graphic on the clipboard saved to disk?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I have a graphic on the clipboard on OS X.

What's the quickest way to get it onto disk as a png or jpg?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Maybe the `File | New From Clipboard` menu of `/Application/Preview.app`.

[image]

Comment: Pressing ⌘N is faster. :)

Comment: @WTP It does show that in the image. :P I included it for that purpose.

Answer (score 50):

[Here](http://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste) is a utility to do just that.

> #### pngpaste
>
> Paste PNG into files, much like pbpaste does for text.
>
> However instead of `pngpaste > thefile.png`, it's `pngpaste thefile.png`, so one does not accidentally barf binary into the console.

Comment: That rocks. You cranked that out pretty quick.

Comment: You are my hero

Comment: I custom a shell function to save and then select it in finder:     function pngp {
      local path=~/Downloads/${1-000}.png
      pngpaste $path | open -R $path
    }

Comment: Install with: `brew install pngpaste`

Comment: This is buggy, see https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste/issues/16

Answer (score 29):

If you have Preview.app open you can simply 'create new' <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and that will generate the proper canvas and paste the clipboard image. Only thing left to do is save that file. Presto!

Answer (score 10):

Not nearly as slick, but without using Preview.

Finder -> Edit -> Show Clipboard

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> to get the screen shot marquee tool, and copy the part of the clipboard you want. It's now a PNG on your desktop. But probably not *precisely* the same image file.

But at that rate, you probably could have screen-captured the original source using the same method and went right to the PNG without using the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Jeff... was trying to do that myself when you changed it. Never noticed that you could format the keys like that!

Comment: Additionally, if you add Control to the screenshot command above, it will screenshot to clipboard and not a file.  I realize that's the opposite of the OPs question, but it never hurts to close the circle.

Answer (score 7):

From terminal, you can get an image from the clipboard with `osascript`.

Define the following functions. The first function gets the clipboard contents as a string of hex digits. The second function decodes the hex digits into binary.

```bsh
# get clipboard as <class>
getclip() {
  local class=$1; shift; : ${class:?}
  osascript -e "get the clipboard as «class ${class}»"
}

# get clipboard as <class> (decoding hex string)
getclipb() {
  local class=$1; shift; : ${class:?}
  getclip "$class" | sed "s/«data ${class}//; s/»//" | xxd -r -p
}
```

```bsh
$ getclipb PNGf >x.png
```

You can print the clipboard information (current set of data formats & sizes) with this function:

```sh
# print clipboard info
cbi() {
  osascript -e "clipboard info" |
  sed -E 's/, /,/g; s/,([0-9]+)/:\1/g' | tr ':,' '\t\n'
}
```

```sh
$ cbi | expand -t 16
«class PNGf»    3970
«class 8BPS»    4610
GIF picture     60
«class jp2 »    4367
JPEG picture    4877
TIFF picture    4810
«class BMP »    534
«class TPIC»    68
```

Comment: Excellent! For PNG, just `osascript -e "get the clipboard as «class PNGf»" | sed "s/«data PNGf//; s/»//" | xxd -r -p > x.png` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using **Preview.app** is a way, but a little cumbersome. It can also be done on the command line.

Because `pbpaste` can only `pbpaste > filename` text snippets, you want to use `pngpaste` instead.

Install it with Brew:

```
brew install pngpaste
```

and use it:

```
pngpaste <filename>
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise the original question calls for saving as a PNG or JPEG, but...

I use a script that saves any graphic on the clipboard to a new page in a PDF document, thus sort-of replicating the old 'Scrapbook' app on Classic MacOS.

The 'quickest way' bit is that I save the script to `/Library/Scripts`, so I can execute it from the Scripts menulet in the menubar. (which you can enable in the AppleScript `Script Editor.app`'s Preferences dialog).

The images can be copy-and-pasted for other purposes or exported as images.

```
#!/usr/bin/python   
# getPDFclip v.1.3 : Get PDF from Clipboard image data.
# This script saves a PDF with a copy of any image data found on the Mac Clipboard.   
# If Clipboard.pdf exists, the image is added as an extra page.

from AppKit import NSPasteboard, NSPasteboardTypePDF, NSPasteboardTypeTIFF, NSPasteboardTypePNG, NSTIFFPboardType, NSPICTPboardType, NSImage
from Foundation import NSURL
import Quartz as Quartz
import os, syslog

# Change this to whatever filepath you want:
outfile=os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Clipboard.pdf")


myFavoriteTypes = [NSPasteboardTypePDF, NSPasteboardTypeTIFF, NSPasteboardTypePNG, NSTIFFPboardType, NSPICTPboardType, 'com.adobe.encapsulated-postscript']
pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
best_type = pb.availableTypeFromArray_(myFavoriteTypes)
if best_type:
    clipData = pb.dataForType_(best_type)
    if clipData:
        image = NSImage.alloc().initWithPasteboard_(pb)
        if image:
            page = Quartz.PDFPage.alloc().initWithImage_(image)
        if os.path.exists(outfile):
            pdfURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(outfile)
            myFile = Quartz.PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(pdfURL)
            if myFile:
                pagenum = myFile.pageCount()
                myFile.insertPage_atIndex_(page, pagenum)
                print ("Image added to Clipboard file.")
        
        else:
            pageData = page.dataRepresentation()
            myFile = Quartz.PDFDocument.alloc().initWithData_(pageData)
        myFile.writeToFile_(outfile)
        print ("Clipboard file created.")

else:
    print ("No clipboard image data was retrieved.")
    print ("These types were available:")
    print (pb.types())
```

Answer (score 1):

Did not get @HappyFace zsh approach to work so created a traditional bash version:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/428168

#
# you might want to save this script to
# $HOME/bin/jpgpaste and do a
# ln -s jpgpaste cpngpaste and
# chmod +x jpgpaste cpngpaste


# paste the clibpoard to a png file
function pngpaste() {
    local name="$1.png"
    local folder=$(pwd)

    osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to ¬
                  write (the clipboard as «class PNGf») to ¬
                          (make new file at folder \"$folder\" with properties ¬
                                  {name:\"${name}\"})"
}

# paste the clipboard to a jpg file
function jpgpaste() {
    local name="$1.jpg"
    local folder=$(pwd)

    osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to ¬
                  write (the clipboard as JPEG picture) to ¬
                          (make new file at folder \"$folder\" with properties ¬
                                  {name:\"${name}\"})"
}

script=$(basename $0)
case $script in
  jpgpaste)
    jpgpaste "$1"
    ;;
  cpngpaste)
    pngpaste "$1"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

~If you already use Alfred or a clipboard Manager ~

I use Alfreds Clipboard History Manager (You can use any free clipboard manager to do this too, provided it also keeps a history of images not just text)

Alfred saves all my clipboard image screenshots and saves them in it's history of snippets.

[image: My Clipboard History in Alfred (it gets purged every 24H)]

I then set/create a folder action (using Automator) to copy everything that gets saved into Alfreds Clipboard History folder*

*(located in Library/applicationsupport/alfred/databses/alipboard.alfdp.data

[image: This is where Alfred saves Clipboard Image History (or find your clipboard managers image history folder)]

to duplicate those images over to my screenshots folder/downloads/desktop. (alfred deletes my clipboard history every 24H)

[image: Use Automator - Folder Actions - Select the clipboard image history folder location and copy the finder contents to your screenshots folder / desktop / downloads etc]

Now I always have a saved copy of the screenshot on my disk as well as the screenshot sitting in my clipboard. :]

Comment: I wish so bad that I could just drag the images out of Alfred's Clipboard History Manager. Could you show us what this folder action looks like?

Answer (score 0):

```
setopt rematchpcre

function pngpaste() {
    local name="${1}"

    [[ "$name" =~ '\.png$' ]] || name+=.png

    osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to ¬
                  write (the clipboard as «class PNGf») to ¬
                          (make new file at folder \"$(pwd)\" with properties ¬
                                  {name:\"${name}\"})"
}

function jpgpaste() {
    local name="${1}"


    [[ "$name" =~ '\.jpg$' ]] || name+=.jpg

    osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to ¬
                  write (the clipboard as JPEG picture) to ¬
                          (make new file at folder \"$(pwd)\" with properties ¬
                                  {name:\"${name}\"})"
}
```

Usage:

```
pngpaste a1.png
#or
jpgpaste a1.jpg
```

Comment: what to do with this code? Is this applescript? how is it made to be executed?

Comment: @WolfgangFahl It’s zsh, and it might also work with bash. You can paste the function definitions directly to the default terminal app, and then ise them as indicated. If you’re still confused, read some quick start guide on zsh.

Comment: -thanks for the quick answer. I have used bash and ksh for years bug zsh is greek to me. You  might want to add a zsh sheebang to make clear what your up to. Does this have to go to the profile or should it be two scripts or links for the same file ?

Comment: jpgpaste:2: command not found: ensure-args
jpgpaste:3: command not found: ensure
63:92: execution error: „System Events“ hat einen Fehler erhalten: Einige Daten können nicht in den erwarteten Typ umgewandelt werden. (-1700)

Comment: @WolfgangFahl I had somehow forgotten to delete some extra assertions from the code, which would need my own custom code loaded. Try it now, it should work.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl BTW, the last System Events error that you got has to do with macOS permissions. Try to give full accessibility permission to your terminal app.

Comment: thx for looking into this i am happy with my bash script. Learning zsh will be somethign I'll do if i have a need.

Answer (score -2):

I like to use the command line:

```
pbpaste > myfile.png
```

The pbcopy command is useful as well. See [this post](http://osxdaily.com/2009/12/09/access-the-clipboard-from-the-command-line/) for details.

Comment: I just tested it, and `pbpaste` only works with plain text, rich text, etc. No binary data. See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146692/binary-image-data-clipboard-os-x)

Comment: -1 as it doesn't actually work for the question he asked.

Comment: Bummer, thought for sure it would work with binary but didn't test (mac is at home, not here at work). Got the StackOverflow urge to post something as fast as I could. Tried to downvote my own answer but I couldn't.  :)

Comment: Oh hells yeah. This is rad -- despite the obvious failure suggested by others.

Comment: There's always the "delete" link!

Comment: Delete link is good to use, since the answer is very misleading. Better use `pngpaste` as [mentioned in an answer below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282170/235780)