# Is there a built-in way to both save and copy a screenshot to the clipboard at the same time?

Tags: terminal, screen-capture

From what I've seen it seems like the basic hotkeys do not allow such a thing, besides if I use the following command on the terminal :

```
screencapture -ci somepath/screenshot.jpg
```

It only copies the screenshot to the clipboard but doesn't create the file screenshot.jpg at all (-c copies to clipboard and -i makes the user select a rectangle region to capture)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `man screencapture` one can only save to the clipboard **or** to a file: there doesn't seem to be any way around this as designed.

The description of the command uses the word 'or' to indicate that only one action is possible: save the screencapture to a file or to the clipboard:

[image]

Comment: Where do you see in "man creencapture" that this is not possible ?

Comment: Edited answer to show unambiguous language in man description. 'Or' means 'or'.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question:
[What's the quickest way to get a graphic on the clipboard saved to disk?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11100/whats-the-quickest-way-to-get-a-graphic-on-the-clipboard-saved-to-disk)

And this utility:

> #### [pngpaste](http://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste)
>
> Paste PNG into files, much like pbpaste does for text.