# How can I paste a screenshot image from clipboard into a folder?

Tags: finder, screen-capture, copy-paste

My screenshots go directly to my clipboard, which works for me most of the time, so I'm not trying to change that behavior.

What I want to do is paste said screenshot into a folder of my choosing.

Finder doesn't seem to let me paste my screenshots from my clipboard into folders, so now I'm looking for a workaround that uses as few steps as possible.

**The suboptimal Approach**: I've found that I can open these images from my clipboard in Preview, but then I have to re-save them to a desired folder, which is too cumbersome to be considered a solution.

**What I'm looking for**: Something with fewer steps than the above approach. I just need to get the image from my clipboard into a folder of my choosing. If you can do better, you'll save me and others a lot of time.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) `My screenshots go directly to my clipboard, which works for me most of the time, so I'm not trying to change that behavior.` How have you set this up? By default screenshots in macOS are saved on Desktop.

Comment: Understood. I have it set up so they go to my clipboard. What I'm asking is how to get an image from my clipboard to a folder that I decide after I've taken the screenshot.

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you using? Also, what format do you want the clipboard image to be saved as, e.g. **PNG**?

Comment: Im not understanding why the need to change the default behavior of getting a screen shot, because all you have do do to send it to the clipboard is hold ‘Control’ while you take it.  Anyway...you have to paste it to something that will save it as a file - you can’t get around that requirement.

Comment: @Allan, RE: "Anyway...you have to paste it to something that will save it as a file - you can’t get around that requirement." -- That is not true as the contents of the clipboard **can** be written to a disk file without having to first paste it somewhere.

Comment: @user3439894 Ok.  I don’t mind being wrong.  Can you explain how to accomplish this?

Comment: @Allan, When I press **⇧⌘6**, on my system, I get either a message saying there is not an image on the clipboard, or a choose folder dialog asking where to save the clipboard image. If there is an image on the clipboard it gets saved as e.g. **Screen Shot 2020-05-21 at 2.29.55 PM.png** and this of course is due to the _code_ I wrote for it to happen.  This is why I asked the OP "What version of **macOS** are you using? Also, what format do you want the clipboard image to be saved as, e.g. **PNG**?" so I can adjust it accordingly and post an answer.

Comment: That's the Screenshot App (aka Grab) that has the image.  It's not going directly from the clipboard to a file, but the App is saving what's in the clipboard to a file.   But if that can solve the OP's issue, then by all means post as an answer!

Comment: @Allan, RE: "That's the Screenshot App (aka Grab) that has the image." -- I am not using that! The _code_ I've written looks at what already on the clipboard, regardless of how it got there, and if it contains graphic image data it then reads directly from the clipboard and is written to disk file after choosing where it's to be written.

Comment: *The code I've written looks at what already on the clipboard, regardless of how it got there...*. So, an app then?  I'm not sure why there's so much debate around the fact that the clipboard cannot write files to the disk and that an app, self coded or off the shelf, must be involved to achieve the OP's desired result.

Comment: @Allan, RE: "I'm not sure why there's so much debate around the fact that the clipboard cannot write files to the disk" -- **I never said the clipboard could write files to disk!** Why don't you just leave it at the fact that the statement you made "_Anyway...you have to paste it to something that will save it as a file - you can’t get around that requirement._" **is not true!** There is **no pasting involved** in what I've written to write the graphic image data to disk file and is not in app form but could also be if I wanted. Why you have tried to escalate this is beyond me!

Comment: OMG @user3439894 ...you're hanging this on a single not-so-accurate word "pasting????"  Seriously....remember the audience.  I wrote my comment for the non-technical user.  So yes, you're correct - there's no "pasting" to the file.  My point, however, stands - you need a third party app.  And all your commenting did nothing to disprove that point.  As for the "escalation" you're the one that felt the need to correct me because you didn't like the usage of a single word.  Let's keep things in perspective.

Comment: I’m not sure what’s going on, but in case there was any confusion there is a way to get macOS to automatically save the screen to the clipboard. I’m assuming OP wants a way to save the clipboard to a file without having to change this behavior.

Comment: @JamieSlate: Welcome to AskDifferent SE. It appears you've hit the jackpot! In addition to the answers below, your question has been asked before (or a reasonable facsimile of it), and received excellent answers: [Ans 1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309800/149366) and [Ans 2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/11116/149366).

Comment: various solutions for this are given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11100/whats-the-quickest-way-to-get-a-graphic-on-the-clipboard-saved-to-disk)

Answer (score 5):

### Edit/Re-Write # 2:

My earlier answers were wrong, and while troubleshooting, new (and likely better) answers have been posted. Nevertheless, I've finally got a correct answer, so I'm going to post it. I've tested it with screenshots on  my 10.15.4 system, and it worked reliably in my (limited) testing. As there were already answers to this question that required only minor adaptation, I relied heavily upon them - [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/365231/149366), and  [this one in particular](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309800/149366), both posted by @CJK.

This answer requires use of the command line. It uses only resources that are *native* to macOS 10.15.4, and there are no work-arounds offered. Here's what I did:

Start the `Terminal` app, and then from the shell (`zsh`) prompt (`%`) start the editor of your choice to open the `~/.zshrc` file in your *"home"* (`$HOME`) directory. I've used `nano` here:

```
% nano ~/.zshrc
```

When the editor opens, you may have only an empty file - that's fine. If there is something in the file, just **move the insertion point to the end of the file**, then copy and paste the following text into the editor:

```
function pss () {
    folder=$(pwd)
    filename="Screen Shot $(date +%Y-%m-%d\ at\ %H.%M.%S).png"

    if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
        if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
            if [ "$1" != "." ]; then folder=$1; fi
        else
            a=$(dirname "$1")
            b=$(basename "$1" .png)

            if [ "$b" != "" ]; then filename=$b.png; fi

            if [ "$a" != "." ]; then folder=$a; fi
        fi
    fi

    osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to ¬
            write (the clipboard as «class PNGf») to ¬
            (make new file at folder \"$folder\" ¬
            with properties {name:\"$filename\"})"
}
```

Save the file, and exit the editor. You have now created a [*shell function*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-shell-functions.htm) named `pss` (for **p**aste **s**creen **s**hot).

Before you can use this *shell function*, you'll need to `source` this change to `zsh` (a logout/login, or reboot will accomplish the same thing, but this is easier):

```
% . ~/.zshrc
# OR, ALTERNATIVELY:
% exec zsh
```

Take a screenshot as you've configured it now - with the output going to the clipboard.

Finally, use the `pss` function to copy/save the screenshot to the a file in your desired location:

```
% pss /Users/yourid/yourfolder
```

A couple of notes:

1. The filename has been set in the `pss` function to approximate the default filename used by the system for screenshots. If you wish to change that, modify the following line:

```
filename="Screen Shot $(date +%Y-%m-%d\ at\ %H.%M.%S).png"
```

2. You do not need to always specify the folder location. If you `cd` to the directory in which you wish to save your screenshot files, you can simply run the `pss` function without an argument. For example, you wish to save your screenshot files to `/Home/user/screenshots`:

```
% cd /Home/user/screenshots
# make your screenshot
% pss
# the screenshot file is created in this (the `pwd`) directory
```

Comment: The default in **macOS Catalina**, as well as previous version of **macOS**, for **US English**, is e.g., **Screen Shot 2020-05-22 at 1.32.55 AM.png**, not e.g. Screen Shot 2020-05-22 at 01.32.55.png as you've coded. For the default, with the aforementioned **Language & Region** setting, the _time string_ would be represented as `%l.%M.%S %p` as shown I'm my answer. Obviously, this specific _format_ will differ based on **Language & Region** setting, but in this particular use case will be as it's defined in the _script_.

Answer (score 3):

I created an [automator](https://support.apple.com/guide/automator/welcome/mac) workflow to solve this problem

Bottom line: the solution allows you to save an image from the clipboard anywhere with one keystroke (you have to show it where to go in the save dialogue, obviously)

The workflow opens preview, creates a new file from the clipboard, and saves the file (opening the save as dialogue). You can then put it wherever you want. Here's the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZumGgx5PUsbmxT4JjZn3MISiLqxJ1VSZ) to a zip with the workflow. To run the workflow, you'll probably need to approve automator with certain permissions (it'll pop up if and ask for approval, so don't worry if you don't run into this problem). Open the zip, then double click the file (make sure there's an image in the clipboard). A new file should open in preview and ask to be saved.

To create a shortcut, just go to 'keyboard' under system preferences > 'shortcuts' > 'services' and setup the shortcut.

Comment: I worked, but every time I invoke the action it prompts me to enter my password. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

On occasion, I too have *graphic image data* from a **screen shot** on the **clipboard** and have used a very stripped down version of the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown further below to write it to a disk file. However, I've rewritten it so all you have to do is set the value for two *variables*, read the comments in the *code*, then save the *script* using **Script Editor**. Then you can trigger it from a *keyboard shortcut* using an app like [**FastScripts**](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) or similar.

This way you do not need to give every application that has focus separate permission to run it, like you would if you used an **Automator** *Service/QuickAction* set to **any application**. (Or you could just set it to one application, e.g. **Finder** and then only trigger it from there.)

[**FastScripts**](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) is **free** for up to 10 *keyboard shortcuts*. Note that I'm not affiliated with the developer of this product, just a satisfied user.

Save the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* as a *script* named e.g. **Write Clipboard Graphic Image Data to File**, then assign it a *keyboard shortcut* in **FastScripts**, I used **⇧⌘6**, and start using it. Note that you can also use it in a **Run Shell Script** *action* in an **Automator** *Service/QuickAction* if you want to, but **FastScripts** is the way to go.

If you want to hard code a *location*, instead of a **choose folder** *dialog*, just let me know and I can change the *code*.

What this *example* **AppleScript** *code* does:

- Checks the **clipboard** to see if it contains *graphic image data* and if not informs the user.
- If the **clipboard** does contain *graphic image data* a **choose folder** *dialog* opens.
- Choose the *location* to save the *graphic image data* from the **clipboard** to *file*, and it does, unless you do not have *write permission* to that *location*, you are warned and then choose again.
- The *naming convention* is, e.g.: **Screen Shot 2020-05-21 at 9.34.29 PM.png**

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  #
--      ### Write Clipboard Graphic Image Data to File ###
--  #
--  # This example AppleScript code will write graphic image data in its normal form on the clipboard to disk file.
--  # All you need to do is set the value of the fileExtension variable to the type of graphic image file you want.
--  # Then when the script runs, a choose folder dialog box will appear, you select a location and click the Choose button.
--  # The graphic image data in its normal form on the clipboard is written to disk file with the following naming convention:
--  # 'Screen Shot 2020-05-21 at 9.34.29 PM.fileExtension' e.g. 'Screen Shot 2020-05-21 at 9.34.29 PM.png'



--  # Set the value of the fileExtension variable 
--  # to the type of graphic image file you want.
--  # 
--  # Valid values are: png, jpg, tiff, gif

set fileExtension to "png"

--  # The defaultChooseFolderLocation is the default
--  # location the choose folder dialog opens to.
--  # It can be any properly formed AppleScript 
--  # 'path to (folder)', or use a fully qualified POSIX path.

set defaultChooseFolderLocation to path to (pictures folder)


--  ########################################
--  ## Do Not Edit Below Unless You Know What You Are Doing. ##
--  ########################################


--  # With the exception of the file naming convention, the rest 
--  # of the code is tokenized and should not need to be edited.
--  # Obviously though, feel free to edit it if you so choose.

if fileExtension is equal to "png" then
    set imageType to «class PNGf»
else if fileExtension is equal to "jpg" then
    set imageType to JPEG picture
else if fileExtension is equal to "tiff" then
    set imageType to TIFF picture
else if fileExtension is equal to "gif" then
    set imageType to GIF picture
else
    display dialog "The file extension set is not recognized!" buttons {"OK"} ¬
        default button 1 with title "Write Clipboard Graphic Image Data to File" with icon stop
    return
end if


if ((clipboard info) as string) contains imageType then
    my chooseLocationAndWriteFile(imageType, fileExtension, defaultChooseFolderLocation)
else
    display dialog "The clipboard does not contain graphic image data!" buttons {"OK"} ¬
        default button 1 with title "Write Clipboard Graphic Image Data to File" with icon caution
end if


--  ## Handler(s) ##

on chooseLocationAndWriteFile(imageType, fileExtension, defaultChooseFolderLocation)
    set cbImage to (the clipboard as imageType)
    set fileName to do shell script ¬
        "echo $(date '+Screen Shot %Y-%m-%d% at %l.%M.%S %p." & fileExtension & "')"
    set saveToLocation to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt ¬
        "Choose the Folder to save the clipboard image to..." default location ¬
        defaultChooseFolderLocation)
    set imageFile to saveToLocation & fileName
    my writeToFile(cbImage, imageFile, true, imageType, fileExtension)
end chooseLocationAndWriteFile

on writeToFile(theData, theFile, overwriteExistingContent, imageType, fileExtension)
    try
        set theOpenedFile to open for access POSIX file theFile with write permission
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        write theData to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        close access theOpenedFile
    on error eStr number eNum
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try
        if eNum is equal to -5000 then
            display dialog ¬
                "You do not have write permission to this location!" buttons {"OK"} ¬
                default button 1 with title "File I/O Error..." with icon stop
            my chooseLocationAndWriteFile(imageType, fileExtension, defaultChooseFolderLocation)
        else
            display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum ¬
                buttons {"OK"} default button 1 ¬
                with title "File I/O Error..." with icon stop
        end if
        return
    end try
end writeToFile
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I combined [user3439894's approach](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391810/201522) with Automator. Result: `^` + `⌥`+ `⌘` + `v` to paste the clipboard to the *current folder*.

### Step 1

Create a new "Quick Action" in `Automator.app` and add the following `Run AppleScript` block:
[image]

```
set imageType to «class PNGf»

if ((clipboard info) as string) contains imageType then
    set theData to (the clipboard as imageType)
    
    -- path
    tell application "Finder" to set saveToLocation to (target of front Finder window) as text
    
    -- filename
    set fileName to do shell script ¬
        "echo $(date '+Screen Shot %Y-%m-%d% at %l.%M.%S %p.png')"
    
    set imageFile to saveToLocation & fileName
    
    
    
    try
        set theOpenedFile to open for access imageFile as «class furl» with write permission
        set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        write theData to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        close access theOpenedFile
    on error eStr number eNum
        try
            close access file imageFile
        end try
        if eNum is equal to -5000 then
            display dialog ¬
                "You do not have write permission to this location!" buttons {"OK"} ¬
                default button 1 with title "File I/O Error..." with icon stop
            my chooseLocationAndWriteFile(imageType, fileExtension, defaultChooseFolderLocation)
        else
            display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum ¬
                buttons {"OK"} default button 1 ¬
                with title "File I/O Error..." with icon stop
        end if
        return
    end try
    
    
else
    display dialog "The clipboard does not contain graphic image data!" buttons {"OK"} ¬
        default button 1 with title "Write Clipboard Graphic Image Data to File" with icon caution
end if
```

Save the action to the default iCloud folder.

### Step 2

In System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services, the new Quick Action should appear:

[image]

Adding a shortcut here didn't work for me ‍♂️, so…

### Step 3

In the "Application Shortcuts", add one with the *exact* name of your file:

[image]

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pngpaste`](https://github.com/jcsalterego/pngpaste).

Install it with `brew install pngpaste`, then run

```bash
$ pngpaste /desired/path/of/you/png/file.png # modify this line
```

And your clipboard image is saved to the folder `/desired/path/of/you/png` with the name `file.png`.

How to run `brew install pngpaste`? Just paste the command into the Terminal app. If it says `brew: command not found`, visit https://brew.sh for instructions for installing Homebrew.